# How to change the existing images embedded in Views Twig template to S3 bucket URL

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have embedded the images using views twig template,

```
file_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri) %}
```

The output is `public://2018-07/10a_0_0.JPG`

Instead, I need the image URL from the s3 bucket: https://s3.bucketname/2018-07/10a_0_0.JPG

Note: I have configured amazon s3 and moved the local files to s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
$settings['s3fs.use_s3_for_public'] = TRUE;
```

After that clear cache, now your site images will render form Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi Ajay,  I used as below {{ file_create_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri) }}, but it throws error. as  Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown "file_create_url" function."

Comment: Use it as `file_create_url(file_url(row['content']'#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri) %})`

Comment: Hi Ajay,

I used both methods:

Step1: 

      {% set photo = file_create_url(file_url(row['content']'#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri) %}) 

<img src="{{photo}}">


Step2: 
 {% set photo = file_create_url(file_url(row['content']'#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri))  %}
<img src="{{photo}}">

But the below error is encountered.  Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unclosed "("."

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unclosed "("."

I have used as below:
{% set photo = file_create_url(file_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri))  %}  

<img src="{{photo}}">

Comment: In step 1 missing closed bracket `file_create_url(file_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_future_program_image.entity.fileuri) %}))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82293/discussion-between-ajay-reddy-and-user3613207).